# Expanded variable not evaluating

Tags: batch-file

In the following routine, I'm trying to get the byt variable to expand using a variable for the number. For some reason, it's not expanding. I've tried every variation of call set and doubling the !!'s I can think of. Hopefully it's something simple I'm missing.

```
call :ConvertBytes 10200300200 MB ret
echo %ret% MB
exit /b

:ConvertBytes bytes unit ret
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set byt=%1
if "%~2" EQU "KB" set val=3
if "%~2" EQU "MB" set val=6
if "%~2" EQU "GB" set val=9
if "%~2" EQU "TB" set val=12
endlocal & for %%a in (%val%) do (
  echo !byt:~-%%a!)
exit /b
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move `endlocal` AFTER the `!...!` reference - such references will only expand while `enabledelayedexpansion` is in effect.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple I was missing.